# High impedance state on SPI lines

Tags: relay, spi, buffer

I use an Orange Pi platform for flashing SPI chips soldered directly to the board. Chips are packed in an SO-8 package so I have to use 5250 pomona clip. There are no problems with flashing platform but there are issues when it comes to boot the platform. I want to boot my platform without removing a pomona clip. I've used a TXS0104E logic level converter. This chip features a tri-state buffer as well but it hasn't solved my problem.

Sometimes I need to unplug the MISO cable only and my platform starts but it is not repetitive.

I'm thinking of another solution. What do you think of building a buffer based on 4 relays? Maybe it's controversial a bit because of using the mechanic elements but I think I would have a certain disconnection the SPI interface?

A
Of course, I will make sure if the chosen relays handle such frequency.

Or maybe you have another proposals of solution? What do you think?

Comment: A schematic showing what's connected to what (and what does the Pomona clip connect to?) would probably help people understand your question.

Comment: You don't need relays for this, tristate buffers will do.  Unclear why you disconnect MISO, that is the one line you could typically leave connected.  Seems like you need to better investigate the problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton All of the lines have to be connected. I have added a resistor 1.5k in series in SCLK line in SPI and it works. High-Z state in a tri-state buffer is necessary as well. The buffer itself works good and it's not damaged. I have no explanation why such solution has given good result. Do you know why?

Comment: No, because you've not provided any meaningful information.  Nor does the obvious fact that "all the lines have to be connected" *for operation* have any bearing on "Unclear why you disconnect MISO, that is the one line you could typically leave connected" *when trying to logically detach*